# What's the crater in the mountain shown after Izuku talks to Kota in season 3 episode 3?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In My Hero Academia last episode, after Izuku talks to Kota, they show a sort of crater in the mountain. Does the manga say anything or help to guess what this could be? Does this have any relation with Kota?

[image]

Comment: I guess it's kind of a landing mark left my the villains who came to attack the summer camp. Will have to wait for the anime to show it, or maybe someone who has read the manga can answer this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's his quirk,

> water creation.

He doesn't really do much with it.

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE! Thank for participating on this site, a Q&A site about anime & manga. Seems you have taken a quick [tour], that's great! You might also interested in [how to write a good answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), [how to write a good question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and [formatting help](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). I helped to add the spoiler by starting the paragraph with `>!`. We hope you can participate further in this site and enjoy~!